# About Firebase Authentication with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I'm doing this project these days and for that, I'm using firebase with React. In my project, I have two types of users 1. Student and 2. teacher, so in my site I want to use the same email id to create an account of both the stakeholders from one user, but firebase is not allowing me because I can create only one account using CREATEUSERWITHEMAILANDPASSWORD() method. so how can I create a teacher account if I already have a student account with one email id??

I know this question sounds childish but I am still learning.
so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/your-project-name/authentication/providers and scroll down to advanced, you can find a setting for allowing only one or multiple accounts per email.

You cannot, however, create multiple accounts with the same login method. So you cannot have users create two accounts with email & password. One account could be with email & password and another could be Facebook login, for example.